# Programatically creating variables for use with IN statements

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000, ssrs-2008

Please consider the following scripts.

Create Table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Colortable') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE ColorTable

CREATE TABLE Colortable (Color VARCHAR(32))
GO
```

Insert some values:

```
SET  NOCOUNT ON

INSERT Colortable
  SELECT 'red'

INSERT Colortable
  SELECT 'orange'

INSERT Colortable
  SELECT 'blue'

INSERT Colortable
  SELECT 'green'
GO
```

Create my Variable (which will become a paramter in SSRS) automatically:

DECLARE @colors   VARCHAR(1024)

```
SELECT @colors =
         COALESCE(
           @colors + '''' + ',' + '''', '') +
         Color
FROM Colortable
```

When I use "Select @colors" I get the following:

```
'red','orange','blue','green'
```

However, my queries do not work as expected.

```
SELECT *
FROM colortable
WHERE Color IN ('red', 'orange', 'blue', 'green') -- Returns 4 rows. 


SELECT *
FROM colortable
WHERE Color IN (@colors) -- Returns 0 Rows
```

Can anyone tell me why? I am trying to generate a string of values so that this script will work in SSRS and SSMS (or whatever tool I am using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) may work for you

Comment: +1: Correct - using a single variable to represent a list of comma separated values means dynamic SQL.

Comment: @etliens : there is still one not i.e not +1

Answer (score 1):

@colors is a single varchar, not a list of varchars. What you can do instead is insert your values into a temp table and join against that.

Comment: I can't do that because the SQL Statement is to be used in SSRS (converted to a parameter) and in SSMS as a SQL Statement. If I try to use a table variable, a table of any kind, etc it won't work as a SSRS parameter.

Comment: Why can't SSRS call a stored procedure?  You can do whatever you want in a stored procedure and not have to deal with the limitations of a single SQL statement.

Comment: I'm not allowed to create SP's in my database per the Vendor Contract. It sucks, but it's what I am stuck with.